# What command is sent from AVRDUDE to an AVR programmer for programming ATmega8

Tags: atmega, atmel, avrdude

I have implemented an IoT ATMEL AVR Programmer based on protocol stk500, and I successfully connect with it wirelessly and program any ATMEL AVR Programmer through Arduino IDE, My Question is: I need for example the set of commands that are sent from AVRDUDE to my programmer that programs ATMEL AVR ATmega8.

I'm trying to send command from an Android device to program that microcontroller wirelessly.

Thanks,,,,

Comment: I think that if you implemented the protocol, you may be able to find the list of commands. http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html this is a good start. But it work from PC to avrdude, where the driver would send the commands through the USB to the programmer. How to make a wireless driver is up to you. You may need to rewrite the Avrdude probably...

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc2591.pdf

Comment: Can you use the Arduino IDE?  Under File:Preferences turn on Verbose outputs. Then duplicate the messages going from the PC to your programmer, have them come from your Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on avrdude internal specifics is lacking. Your best bet may be porting the source code ([link](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avrdude/)). However, I would not attempt to port it to Android, it would be quite a lot of work. Instead, cross-compile it to the microcontroller on the programmer (if it's running some Linux OS this should be easy enough), and send from Android only the command-line options.

How to make avrdude recognize the device it is on as the actual programmer itself may be difficult, though achievable with some file piping or symbolic linking. If needs must, you could consider using a secondary micro just to run avrdude.